# XPath selector Selenium WebDriver, unable to use ID

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Selenium IDE exported this for Java/Junit

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".x-btn-inner:contains('Yes')")) .click();
```

and it doesn't work because contains doesn't exist in CSS. So I want to pass by XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//.x-btn-inner[contains(., 'Yes']")).click();
```

this code isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

```
<span id="button-1006-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-small x-btn-text    x-btn-button-center "><span id="button-1006-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-small  " style=""></span><span id="button-1006-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small">Yes</span></span>
```

The id is dynamically generated so I can't make use of it.

Comment: FWIW it is because `contains` is a selector added on by jQuery etc, and is not part of the official CSS selector standard, and thus won't work in WebDriver land - due to the actual browsers not understanding what 'contains' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get it by text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[. = 'Yes']")).click();
```